# Copy/Move Yocto Project To Another Computer

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, raspberry-pi3, yocto

I have a working Yocto project for Raspberry Pi 3 built on a Ubuntu 16.04.4 PC. This needs to be transferred to a second Ubuntu 16.04.4 PC.

`poky`, `meta-embedded` and `meta-raspberry` were obtained with git `clone -b`.

Due to a poor internet connection this took several days to build an image with bitbake.

My question is, is it possible to copy all of the downloads generated by bitbake on the first PC to the second PC, so that with the `local.conf` and `bblayers.conf` from the first PC bitbake will build the image successfully?

Ideally, on the second PC bitbake will restart from the last successful download copied from the first machine (where?) to the second PC. Bitbake was re-run 10+ times on the first PC, seemingly without significant repetition of execution steps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy DL_DIR folder and SSTATE_DIR folder from one PC to another for minimum rebuild time.

You can also use [SSTATE_MIRRORS](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-SSTATE_MIRRORS) and [own-mirrors](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#setting-up-effective-mirrors) if you want to use multiple computers with same Yocto environment.